# Format of the String and how to get the value from it

Tags: math, logic

I am working on analysis project where they are some messages

```
​Ex : $PAVBADC,08,1.7,5.7,5.6,6.4,1.5,5.8,5.5,4.2,CB4*74~02

     a:         1-8,number of following analogous values
     xx.xxx: analogous value
     name:   source description
     hh:        checksum

CB4,AA,0,--------azimuth 1 - setpoint rpm from lever:%:2.1:2.4:8.1:0:0:100
CB4,AA,1,--------azimuth 1 - rpm feedback:rpm:5.5:5.5:9.2:0:0:300
CB4,AA,2,--------azimuth 1 - setpoint steering from lever:°:9.5:5.5:1.6:-180:0:180
CB4,AA,3,--------azimuth 1 - steering feedback:°:9.5:5.5:1.6:-180:0:180
CB4,AA,4,--------azimuth 2 - setpoint rpm from lever:%:2.1:2.4:8.1:0:0:100
CB4,AA,5,--------azimuth 2 - rpm feedback:rpm:5.5:5.5:9.2:0:0:300
CB4,AA,6,--------azimuth 2 - setpoint steering from lever:°:9.4:5.4:1.6:-180:0:180
CB4,AA,7,--------azimuth 2 - steering feedback:°:9.4:5.6:1.6:-180:0:180
```

Can anyone explain how get the value by comparing the analogue value with the range give
like

```
1.7 -> %:2.1:2.4:8.1:0:0:100
```

I tried a lot but not able to find.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What language are you working in? What are a, xx.xxx, name, and hh? How do they relate to the messages you're showing us? What value are you trying to get?

Comment: @Kevin 1.7,5.7,5.6,6.4,1.5,5.8,5.5,4.2 are the analogue values.

Comment: @Kevin The above message is a NMEA Sentence, which are collected from a voyage i.e form Voyage data collector which similar to black box which has information of the propellers and thrust information.

Comment: @Kevin And I have understand that each values are in the range for 1.7 -> 2.1:2.4:8.1 and moving 0::0:100%. Similarly others . But I am not getting how to calculate the value by using it.